# How to approximately solve a function $f(x,y)$ with binary search?

Tags: number-theory, numerical-methods, approximation

Usually when we have a **monotonic** function $f(x)$ and we know it has a root in $[a,b]$, we can repetitively apply binary search to the region $[a,b]$ so that you get an root $\epsilon$ close to the real root for any arbitrary $\epsilon$.

So naturally my questions asks about a function such as $f(x,y)$. What conditions are needed to perform binary search? If I know that it has a solution in the circle $x^2+y^2 \leq r^2$, can I somehow approximate $(x,y)$ such that if the real roots are $(x*, y*)$ then the binary search returns $(x',y')$ where $\sqrt{(x'-x*)^2+(y'-y*)^2} \leq \epsilon $ ?

Comment: In one dimension binary search is equivalent to the bisection method. For generalization to higher dimensions see e.g. https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Daniel_Bachrathy/publication/265794509_Bisection_method_in_higher_dimensions_and_the_efficiency_number/links/5718a52a08ae30c3f9f185bd.pdf